# How to use Laravel Input::replace() in testing POST requests

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, http-post

I'm having some trouble using Laravel's `Input::replace()` method to simulate a POST request during unit testing.

According to Jeffrey Way [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-laravel-controllers--net-31456) and [here](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=4652), you can do something like this:

```
# app/tests/controllers/PostsControllerTest.php

public function testStore()
{
    Input::replace($input = ['title' => 'My Title']);</p>

    $this->mock
         ->shouldReceive('create')
         ->once()
         ->with($input);

    $this->app->instance('Post', $this->mock);

    $this->call('POST', 'posts');

    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('posts.index');
}
```

However, I can't get this to work. `Input::all()` and all `Input::get()` calls still return an empty array or null after `Input::replace()` is used.

This is my test function:

```
public function test_invalid_login()
{
    // Make login attempt with invalid credentials
    Input::replace($input = [
        'email'     => 'bad@email.com',
        'password'  => 'badpassword',
        'remember'  => true
    ]);

    $this->mock->shouldReceive('logAttempt')
    ->once()
    ->with($input)
    ->andReturn(false);

    $this->action('POST', 'SessionsController@postLogin');

    // Should redirect back to login form with old input
    $this->assertHasOldInput();
    $this->assertRedirectedToAction('SessionsController@getLogin');
}
```

The `$this->mock->shouldReceive()` doesn't get called with `$input` though - it only gets an empty array. I've confirmed this in the debugger by looking at `Input::all()` and `Input::get()` for each value, and they're all empty.

**TL/DR: How do I send a request with POST data in a Laravel unit test?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482943/laravel-4-unit-tests this worked.

Comment: Should there really be a `</p>` tag after the `Input::replace` call on the first line of the test? I think that is a typo.

Answer (score 9):

You should use `Request::replace()`, not `Input::replace` in order to replace input data for the current request.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer - was looking for a similar Problem. :)

Comment: @Gummibeer Welcome ;)